# Get game request ID / Access Facebook game request notification content

Tags: ios, facebook, request, swift3, facebook-ios-sdk

I am trying to send requests with data to Facebook friends in my app. The requests are successfully sent and I do get notifications. However the message on the notifications is not what I specify (the notification I get is xxxxx sent you a request. I specified Please help me with 5 lives). Also, I can't access any data of the request received.

This is how I'm sending the request:

```
    func sendLifeRequest(index: Int) {
        let content = FBSDKGameRequestContent()
        content.message = "Please help me with 5 lives"
        content.data = "5lives"
        let id = facebookFriends[index].id as NSString
        var to: [NSString] = [NSString]()
        to.append(id)
        content.recipients = to
        FBSDKGameRequestDialog.show(with: content, delegate: self)
    }
```

This is how I'm trying to get it in the other end:

```
     FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "https://graph.facebook.com/me/apprequests?access_token=" + FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString, parameters: nil).start(completionHandler: { (connection, user, requestError) -> Void in
        print(requestError) // prints nil
        print(user)
    })
```

print(user) prints:

```
Optional({
id = "https://graph.facebook.com/me/apprequests";
"og_object" =     {
    id = xxxxxxxxxxxxx;
    type = website;
    "updated_time" = "2016-10-19T05:32:20+0000";
};
share =     {
    "comment_count" = 0;
    "share_count" = 0;
};
```

**Update:** I found out that if I copy the request ID and copy it for graph path it works. Does anyone knows how to get this ID from receivers end

```
func gameRequestDialog(_ gameRequestDialog: FBSDKGameRequestDialog!, didCompleteWithResults results: [AnyHashable : Any]!) {
    print("request sent")
    print(results) // copied ID from here
}
```

and pasted...

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: THE ID HERE, parameters: nil).start(completionHandler: { (connection, user, requestError) -> Void in
    print(requestError) // prints nil
    print(user)
})
```

now print user prints:

```
Optional({
application =     {
    category = Games;
    id = xxxxxxxxxxxx;
    link = "https://www.facebook.com/games/?app_id=1841299476156545";
    name = "Crazy Traffic Saga";
};
"created_time" = "2016-10-24T21:25:34+0000";
data = 5lives;
from =     {
    id = xxxxxxxxxxxx;
    name = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
};
id = xxxxxxxxxxxx;
message = "Please help me with 5 lives";
```

})

The problem is I copied when I log in with the user sending and copied to the user receiving. I still can't just access it just by code from the receiver.

Facebook documentation on Game request says:

"In order to read all the requests for a recipient for you can query the graph as shown below using the recipient's USER ACCESS TOKEN. This will return a list of request ids for that user in the app.

GET https://graph.facebook.com/me/apprequests?access_token=[USER ACCESS TOKEN]"

But thats what I was doing at first...

Comment: The message is not shown in the notification jewel, it is only shown in app center.

Comment: Oooh, thank you. Do you know how can I access the data from the receiver end? @CBroe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. the request should be "/me/apprequests"

so:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me/apprequests", parameters: nil).start(completionHandler: { (connection, user, requestError) -> Void in
})
```